How to change custom selector for darkmode in tailwindcss?
I'm using tailwindcss with nuxt3, how can I change the selector for darkMode in tailwind.config.js?
I know tailwindcss using <html data-mode="dark"> selector for change the darkMode, I want to change the selector to detect <body class="body--dark"> is there anyway to change it?
my file tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  prefix: 'tw-',
  darkMode: ['selector', 'body[class="body--dark"]'], // I guess in here, but I don't know how to config it...
}

my index.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>

</script>

<template>
  <div class="tw-bg-orange-400 tw-dark:tw-bg-blue-800 dark:tw-bg-blue-800 tw-flex tw-justify-center tw-items-center tw-h-20 tw-w-full">
    <button class="tw-inline-block tw-rounded tw-bg-blue-500 tw-px-6 tw-pb-2 tw-pt-2.5 tw-text-xs tw-font-medium tw-uppercase tw-leading-normal tw-text-white tw-shadow-primary-3 tw-transition tw-duration-150 tw-ease-in-out hover:tw-bg-primary-accent-300 hover:tw-shadow-primary-2 focus:tw-bg-primary-accent-300 focus:tw-shadow-primary-2 focus:tw-outline-none focus:tw-ring-0 active:tw-bg-primary-600 active:tw-shadow-primary-2 motion-reduce:tw-transition-none dark:tw-shadow-black/30 dark:tw-hover dark:tw-focus dark:tw-active" @click="$q.dark.toggle()">DarkMode Toggle</button>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped></style>

lightmode using bg-orange-400

my expectation when change to darkmode using bg-blue-800 still not working

This is how I install tailwindcss in nuxt3
https://tailwindcss.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation
This is my reference
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#customizing-the-selector
Extending Tailwind "modes" alongside dark mode

with this selector: 'body[class="body--dark"]', your body tag must only have that class. If you want to make it work with other classes as well ( like: class="body--dark tw-text-lg" ), try body.body--dark

I try change darkMode: ['selector', 'body.body--dark'] still not working, is anything wrong?
this is my complete body tag when change to darkMode <body data-atm-ext-installed="1.28.27" class="desktop no-touch body--dark">
